# Angular Typescript No overload matches this call

Tags: angular

I'm currently new in Typescript and this thing confused me.

I have an observable that retrieve an http get request.

**THE ERROR**

Below code will throw `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Object'`

```
getFile() {
  return this.http.get('url');
}

example() {
 getFile.subscribe(result => {
  // the result has a name property in it, confirmed
  const a = result.name;
 });
}
```

**THE ATTEMPT FIX**

```
example() {
 getFile.subscribe((result: { name: string }) => {
  // the result has a name property in it, confirmed
  const a = result.name;
 });
}
```

Why above code doesn't work and Typescript throw `No overload matches this call` and how do I fix it?

I know I can fix it by

```
getFile() {
  return this.http.get<InterfaceThatHasNameKeyInIt>('url');
}
```

but I'm sure that the attempt fix code above is working in my other project (Ionic) but not in a stand alone Angular project.

Has something changed?

Comment: I would just cast the result after receiving it like `result => { const my= result as {name:string};  const a = result.name; }`

Comment: Angular httpclient parses it to a generic object, you need to there specify what you are receiving, doing it later, "is too late". So `return this.http.get<{ name: string }>('url')` should work. So you have 2 different projects, probably the strict checks depend on how your projects are set up / angular version / typescript version.

Comment: Thank you to both of you. It really helps.